# awk parsing output to file with optirun not working

Tags: linux, bash, file, ubuntu, awk

Noob here.
I have ccminer-cryptonight compiled and running on my ubuntu 16.04 thinkpad.
However, since my nvidia gpu is old and not supported by the latest cuda, I have to use the integrated Intel gpu for X and use bumblebee for ccminer and nvidia gpu so my screen wouldn't freeze...
here is the command I use:

```
optirun ccminer -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://miningpooladdress.com:5000 -u username -p "password" -P -R 15
```

ccminer gives a lot of output I only want to monitor the hashrate since there is a bug when the hashrate goes insanely high which means ccminer has stopped mining, so I have to kill it and restart.
this is the awk command I use to parse hashrate:

```
optirun ccminer -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://miningpooladdress.com:5000 -u username -p "password" -P -R 15 2>&1 | awk '/5400M,/ {print $7}'
```

which parse the line of hashrate readout, my card is NVS 5400M, the output looks like:

```
43.43
54.23
32.67
44.89
xx.xx
xx.xx
```

Now I want to write this output to a log file, I tried:

```
optirun ccminer -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://miningpooladdress.com:5000 -u username -p "password" -P -R 15 2>&1 | awk '/5400M,/ {print $7 >> "logfile"}'
```

and

```
optirun ccminer -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://miningpooladdress.com:5000 -u username -p "password" -P -R 15 2>&1 | awk '/5400M,/ {print $7}' >> "logfile"
```

none of these two works, the "logfile" will be created but remain empty what am I doing wrong? Why can I get the screen output but can't write to the file?
Thanks for helps.

Update regarding ccminer-cryptonight: a simple solution of lazy miner behaviours - run as root ;P

Comment: your 1st attempt `awk '/5400M,/ {print $7 >> "logfile"}'` should work

Comment: Did you try `optirun ccminer -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://miningpooladdress.com:5000 -u username -p "password" -P -R 15 2>&1 | awk '/5400M,/ {print $7}' >> logfile`

Comment: no... it will create the file, but no content. system monitor shows the miner is running tho...

Comment: awk or optirun is probably doing buffering. Try changing your awk command to `awk '/5400M,/ {print $7; fflush()}'`. If that fails try adding a call to `stdbuf -oL -eL` before awk and if that doesn't help try it before `optirun`.

Comment: I wondered if I was doing too much piping... fflush() solves the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

awk is buffering its output so change your awk command to:

```
awk '/5400M,/ {print $7; fflush()}'
```

For other buffering issues, google `stdbuf`.